# Given a point on a sphere, how do I find the angles needed to 'point' at it's center?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, spheres, angle

If I have an algorithm to find a point on a sphere, as follows, how can I determine the angles (in XYZ degrees) needed to 'point' to the center of the sphere?

```
x = -(cos(lat) * sin(-lon))
y = cos(lat) * cos(-lon)
z = sin(lat)
```

The above algorithm works perfectly fine when I need to find a point on a sphere give 'lat' and 'lon' angles. I tried to solve the angles myself by adding 180 degrees to each 'lat' and 'lon', but apparently that's not right because the angles seemed to be kind of random (not really random, they seemed to be in some circular pattern to say the least).

Edit: Perhaps I could further explain this with the following example.
Let's say the starting point is the 'North Pole', or (0.0, 0.0, 1.0) given that the radius is exactly 1.0. The angles needed to point to the center of the sphere from the North Pole are (0.0, 0.0, 90.0) logically, which is somehow derived from (0.0, 0.0, -1.0). So given any other latitude and longitude that is not (0.0, 0.0), which would be the North Pole, what do I need to do to point to the center of the sphere? The only information I have before doing this is the radius, latitude (-180 through 180 degrees), and longitude (-90 through 90 degrees).

(ps. I'd provide what I've tried but I'm at work, I'll edit this again later if it seems required)

EDIT: I was doing some more testing today and found that the Z axis rotation is ALWAYS (-lat + 180.0).

```
LL =  -30.0000, -180.0000 | P =   -0.0000,   -0.8660,   -0.5000 | Rz =    0.0000
LL =  -30.0000, -120.0000 | P =   -0.7500,   -0.4330,   -0.5000 | Rz =  -60.0000
LL =  -30.0000,  -60.0000 | P =   -0.7500,    0.4330,   -0.5000 | Rz = -120.0000
LL =  -30.0000,    0.0000 | P =    0.0000,    0.8660,   -0.5000 | Rz = -180.0000
LL =  -30.0000,   60.0000 | P =    0.7500,    0.4330,   -0.5000 | Rz =  120.0000
LL =  -30.0000,  120.0000 | P =    0.7500,   -0.4330,   -0.5000 | Rz =   60.0000
LL =  -30.0000,  180.0000 | P =    0.0000,   -0.8660,   -0.5000 | Rz =    0.0000
(for more, I posted here: http://pastebin.com/Yx5FpNqt)
```

That is the data using the algorithm above. The `Rz` is the Z axis rotation, and it is correct. I need a way from there to find the `Rx` rotation. `P` is the (XYZ) position. `LL` is the (lat, lon).

Comment: LAT, LON that point away from center are same as those that point towards center

Comment: @Narasimham No, 'LAT' and 'LON' are just radians of 'lat' and 'lon'. I need X, Y, and Z.

Comment: You want $\hat{r}$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates

Comment: You need two angles to specify direction not three. Perhaps you can lookup the inverse transformation for spherical coordinates.

Comment: @ja72 Ok, given the Z angles in the data above, how do I solve for the X angles? Those two angles work, but I don't have an algorithm to get the X angle.

Comment: What `Z` angles and `X` angles? You need to define your coordinate systems and what angles you are measuring/calculating.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am actually trying to figure out the same thing for Three.js.

Answer (score 1):

First transform your coordinates to

$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -r \cos(lat) \sin(lon) \\ r \cos(lat)\cos(lon) \\ r \sin(lat) \end{pmatrix} $$

Your unit direction towards the center comes from the unit vector pointing from $(x,y,z)$ towards $(0,0,0)$

$$ \hat{n} = -\begin{pmatrix} - \cos(lat) \sin(lon) \\  \cos(lat)\cos(lon) \\  \sin(lat) \end{pmatrix}$$

in terms of $(x,y,z)$ this is simply

$$ \hat{n} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{x}{r} \\-\frac{y}{r}\\-\frac{z}{r} \end{pmatrix} $$ with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Now if you know the location $(x,y,z)$ you can get $r$, $lat$ and $lon$ by

$$\begin{align} r & = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\
lon &= -\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \\
lat &= \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right) \end{align} $$

Comment: How do I use that unit vector to get rotations?

Comment: Actually the rotation matrix has the 3 unit vectors for columns

Comment: I still don't understand how to get the rotations I need. Like, I need to somehow get XYZ rotations (NOT positions, that's already done) from the current latitude and longitude.

Comment: There aren't any 3 angles. To define a direction you need 2 angles. Perhaps you need to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

The angle in $z$ is just the negative of the latitude.  Your $x$ coordinate has $+x$ in the direction of LON=$180^\circ$ because of the minus sign.  Is that what you want?  Your $+y$ is in the direction of $+90^\circ$.  That means your coordinate system is left handed.  Adding $180^\circ$ for the angles in $x$ and $y$ should work fine.  Please post some results that do not work.

Comment: Yes, the system is "left handed" so those are correct. As I said in the main post, adding 180 just isn't right. I'll be editing the main post with evidence once I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

You rotate the radial vector of length $R$ on positive x-axis through $\lambda$ towards East in equator plane and next through $ \phi$ from radial direction towards North Pole by $ \phi.$

$$\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix} = R* \begin{pmatrix} \cos \lambda  \sin \phi \\ \cos \lambda \cos \phi  \\ \sin \lambda  \end{pmatrix} $$

To get back to reference position on x-axis reverse the sign of both.

Comment: That's just another way to get the position.